# how to associate uicontroller to custom uiview programmatically

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a custom UIview which is created programmatically. How to associate to it a custom UIViewController (programmatically as well)

Thanks and regards,

Comment: sorry I mean programmatically

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implement `loadView` in the `UIViewController` to create a view hierarchy programmatically without a nib file.

```
- (void)loadView {
    // allocate the subclassed UIView, and set it as the UIViewController's main view
    self.view = [[[UIViewSubclass alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)] autorelease];
}
```

You can continue setting up the view/subview hierarchy in two ways. One is to add them in the custom `UIView`'s initialization method, like so:

```
// in the MyView.m file
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)f {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:f]) {
        // add subviews here
    }
    return self;
}
```

The second way is to continue using the `loadView` method implemented in the `UIViewController` subclass, and just using `[self.view addSubview:anotherView]`. (Alternatively, use the `viewDidLoad` method in the `UIViewController subclass`.)

Note: Replace `initWithFrame`: with whatever the custom `UIView`'s initialization method is (e.g., `initWithDelegate:`).

Comment: You have a memory leak in `loadView`. `view` is a retained property.

Comment: Whoops, didn't notice that. Fixed!

Answer (score 1):

Say the view you created is called `newView` and the controller is `newController`. The simple approach would be:

```
newController.view = newView;
```

But I'd rather subclass `UIViewController` and override its `- (void)loadView` and `- (void)viewDidLoad` methods and create and/or manipulate the view there - that's the way Apple wants you to do it, and for good reason.

Comment: but my custom view is a subview and its parent view has already a controller, how should I create the new controller?

Comment: Where did you get that custom view from? Can't you recreate it from scratch? Note that when moving a subview to a new view (e.g. a new controller) it will disappear from the old view, so you should rather create a new view for the new controller.

If you still want to assign an existing view to the new controller, just create the new controller as usual and then call `newController.view = newView;`, as I said before.